Jekyll install issue: Installation works but won't run
Trying to install Jekyll so as to build Jekyll blog site
Performed steps as specified but Jekyll command (eg jekyll -v) fails.
Context: Windows 11, new installation.
gem install bundler
PS c:\Users\me\source\repos\AzureDevops_SportronicsAU\DJzBlog> gem install bundler
Using rubygems directory:c:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
Successfully installed bundler-2.5.22
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.5.22
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

gem install jekyll
PS c:\Users\me\source\repos\AzureDevops_SportronicsAU\DJzBlog> gem install jekyll
Using rubygems directory:c:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
Successfully installed ffi-1.17.0-x64-mingw-ucrt
Successfully installed google-protobuf-4.28.3-x64-mingw-ucrt
Successfully installed sass-embedded-1.80.4-x64-mingw-ucrt
Successfully installed jekyll-4.3.4
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.17.0-x64-mingw-ucrt
Parsing documentation for google-protobuf-4.28.3-x64-mingw-ucrt
Parsing documentation for sass-embedded-1.80.4-x64-mingw-ucrt
Parsing documentation for jekyll-4.3.4
Done installing documentation for ffi, google-protobuf, sass-embedded, jekyll after 4 seconds
4 gems installed

Check Ruby version
PS c:\Users\me\source\repos\AzureDevops_SportronicsAU\DJzBlog> ruby -v
ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

Check: Jekyll -v (Failure)
PS c:\Users\me\source\repos\AzureDevops_SportronicsAU\DJzBlog> jekyll -v
C:/Users/david/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:354:in `raise_not_found!': Could not find gem 'jekyll (~> 4.0)' in locally installed gems. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:445:in `block in prepare_dependencies'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:420:in `each'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:420:in `map'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:420:in `prepare_dependencies'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:63:in `setup_solver'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:28:in `start'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:633:in `start_resolution'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:306:in `resolve'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:582:in `materialize'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `specs'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:260:in `specs_for'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.22/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `setup'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.4/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
        fromc:/Users/Me/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.4/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'


I'd try with WSL.
